# Message store for persistence delivering to AMQP broker in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration, amqp, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to build integration flow, which will prevent the loss of messages during delivery to AMQP broker (rabbitMQ).
In the case of broker stopping, I see some unexpected for me behavior:

1. Failed messages are saving to the message store, but not for long. This flow isn't waiting for broker availability, it extracts messages from messages store even the broker still be stopped
2. In case of successful restarting of rabbitmq, records from the message-store(if they still are presented) are not be delivered to the queue.

Please help me in investigations. Code Example:

```
 @Bean
public MessageChannel messageStoreBackedChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(
            new MessageGroupQueue(jdbcChannelMessageStore(), "Group_ID")
    );
}

 @Bean
public IntegrationFlow someFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("messageStoreBackedChannel")
            .channel("amqpMessageChannel")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsExtractFlow(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("amqpMessageChannel")
            .handle(message -> System.out.println(message.getPayload()))
            .get();
}


@Bean
public MessageChannel amqpMessageChannel() {
    return new PollableAmqpChannel("amqpMessageChannel", amqpTemplate);
}

@Bean
public JdbcChannelMessageStore jdbcChannelMessageStore() {
    var jdbcChannelMessageStore = new JdbcChannelMessageStore(dataSource);
    jdbcChannelMessageStore.setChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider(new PostgresChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider());

    return jdbcChannelMessageStore;
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata defaultPoller() {
    PollerMetadata pollerMetadata = new PollerMetadata();
    pollerMetadata.setTrigger(new PeriodicTrigger(10));
    return pollerMetadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to configure an endpoint in between your `.from("messageStoreBackedChannel").channel("amqpMessageChannel")` as `transactional()`.

Something like this:

```
.from("messageStoreBackedChannel")
.bridge(e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10).transactional()))
.channel("amqpMessageChannel")
```

So, whenever delivery to the `amqpMessageChannel` fails, a transaction is going to roll back and the failed message will come back to the store until the next poll.

Of course you can stop that `bridge` endpoint when you get an error connecting to RabbitMQ. But how can you determine then that connection comes back?..

Comment: .bridge(e -> e.transactional()) - Didn't change the behaviour for my case. 

The first unsuccessful retry (org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'amqpMessageChannel') delete one record from message store.

Do we have an opportunity to do more than one such retry before the record will be deleted from the store?

Comment: Oh! Wait. try this: `.bridge(e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(10).transactional()))`. The poller must be transactional

Comment: Yes, it fixed my problem. Thank you a lot, it saved my time!

Comment: I have one more question about this topic, please. Does spring integration have any instruments to configure the durability of message in the message-store (For example, it will be deleted after some time or after some count of attempts to resend)

Comment: Since not all persistent stores provides an automatic time-to-live, we don’t have such a feature in the framework to rely on. However we may consider to add something similar to `MessageGroupStoreReaper`, but per message in the group